# how to send data through wifi in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, wifi

please tell me how to send and receive  objects with his parameters to another iphone for my multiplayer game through wifi ..
I am using cocos2d in my game ...
i already spend my 2 days in it please help me ...
i am stuck here ....

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use peer-to-peer connectivity.... [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Peer-To-Peer/Peer-To-Peer.html)
(You must have an Apple ID).

Comment: The peer picker provides a standard user interface for connecting two users via Bluetooth. Optionally, your application can configure the peer picker to allow a user to choose between an Internet and Bluetooth connection. If an Internet connection is chosen, your application must dismiss the peer picker dialog and present its own user interface to complete the connection.